# R statbin_mean with fixed bins of x

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot in R the equivalent of the binscatter command that you can find in Stata.
I have found the statar package that should give the same with the command stat_binmean. 
I am having problems in setting the bins though. I want to set the specific values of x at which I want the bin to be constructed. Indeed , for now, I have only managed to set the number of bins that I want, leaving to R the option to set the corresponding values of x.

The following is my code:

```
library(statar)
library(ggplot2)

g<-ggplot( df , aes(x=var_x , y=var_y))
g + stat_binmean(n=0)
```

From the statar's instruction code: "Set (n) to zero if you want to use distinct value of x for grouping", but how do I specify the specific values of the grouping?

PS: I am also fine with other commands, like stat_summary_bin, but my problem stays the same.

Comment: My guess is that the author means by _"distinct value of x"_ that for each binning will occur for each unique value of x, not that you can supply specific values yourself.

Comment: Perhaps `ggplot(mtcars, aes(cut(hp, 10), qsec)) + stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', geom = 'point')` is equivalent? See `?cut` to set different breaks.